# Some faces are not lit in a matlab mesh plot

Tags: matlab, lighting

I use this command to draw a mesh

```
trimesh(F, X, Y, Z,...
'EdgeColor','k','FaceColor','flat','FaceVertexCData',c, ...
'CDataMapping','scaled','FaceLighting','flat','BackFaceLighting','lit');
camlight;
```

When I do this, most faces are lit as expected, but some appear to be unlit; i.e, evern when I rotate the view to other angles and change the light position (as it is dependent on the camera), I still do not see them lit.

It seems to me like a classical problem with the normals (i.e my normal is in the opposite direction), though I thought that in the call to `trimesh` the arguments `'BackFaceLighting','lit'` take care of that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the renderer to `opengl` by using the following command:

```
set(gcf,'Renderer','opengl');
```

It usually handles 3D better than the standard renderer.